# Globally ignore class in Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

Jackson has ability to skip unknow properties globally using `DeserializationFeature`, but I can't find any global config to ignore whole class from being parsed. I have class with two methods with the same name but with different arguments, so I want to set this class as ignorable globally(using objectMapper object) not just by adding any annotations to model class. May be someone faced with such problem.

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Have you tried with MixIns? Using addMixInAnnotations method in JacksonObjectMapper.

Comment: I don't know a global solution; my first guess would be to mark the fields (which have this type) `transient`, to make Jackson ignore them.

Comment: @UweAllner, tryed to add `addMixInAnnotations` didn't help

Comment: Do you what to ignore all the "setter" property methods with a certain type parameter in all the classes?

Comment: @AlexeyGavrilov, it would be great to set ignorable only one of two methods. But I think this is hard to do (may be impossible make this globally through ObjectMapper). So I want to know, is it possible to ignore whole this class and make Jackson skip this class during marshall and unmarshall.

Comment: Actually it's quite easy to ignore the method based on its meta information such as name, parameters and annotations. I'm just trying to understand your scenario to come up with a workable example. Btw, have check out the @JsonIgnoreType annotation?

Comment: as I previously mentioned, I don't want to mess my model with a Jackson's annotations

Comment: Did my answer help you to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to mark the type you wish to ignore with @JsonIgnoreType annotation. If you don't want to mess your model with Jackson annotations you can use [mix-ins](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations).

Another option is to override [the Jackson annotation introspector](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/AnnotationIntrospector) to ignore the property based on its type.

Here is example shows both:

```
public class JacksonIgnoreByType {
    public static final String JSON = "{\n" +
            "  \"bean1\" : {\n" +
            "    \"field1\" : \"value1\"\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  \"bean2\" : {\n" +
            "    \"field2\" : \"value2\"\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  \"bean3\" : {\n" +
            "    \"field3\" : \"value3\"\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}\n";

    public static class Bean1 {
        public String field1;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Bean1{" +
                    "field1='" + field1 + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    @JsonIgnoreType
    public static class Bean2 {
        public String field2;
    }

    public static class Bean3 {
        public String field3;
    }

    public static class Bean4 {
        public Bean1 bean1;
        public Bean2 bean2;
        public Bean3 bean3;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Bean4{" +
                    "bean1=" + bean1 +
                    ", bean2=" + bean2 +
                    ", bean3=" + bean3 +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector(){
            @Override
            public boolean hasIgnoreMarker(AnnotatedMember m) {
                return m.getRawType() == Bean3.class || super.hasIgnoreMarker(m);
            }
        });

        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(JSON, Bean4.class));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Bean4{bean1=Bean1{field1='value1'}, bean2=null, bean3=null}
```