# Jackson ObjectMapper: How to omit (ignore) fields of certain type from serialization?

Tags: java, json, jackson

How can I tell Jackson ObjectMapper to ignore fields of certain type (class), in my case of `Object.class`, from serialization?

Constrains:

- No control of source class - it is a third party class
- Class type being serialized is unknown upfront - I guess it disqualifies MixIn(s)
- Such field(s) name is unknown upfront

To help, below is a unit test expecting fields `objectsList` and `objectField` to be ignored from serialization, but its approach is not correct, it is filtering them by name instead of by their type.

```
public static class FavoriteShows {
    public Simpsons favorite = new Simpsons();
    public BigBangTheory preferred = new BigBangTheory();
}

public static class Simpsons {
    public String title = "The Simpsons";

    public List<Object> objectsList = List.of("homer", "simpson");
    public Object objectField = new HashMap() {{
        put("mr", "burns");
        put("ned", "flanders");
    }};
}

public static class BigBangTheory {
    public String title = "The Big Bang Theory";

    public List<Object> objectsList = List.of("sheldon", "cooper");
    public Object objectField = new HashMap() {{
        put("leonard", "hofstadter");
        put("Raj", "koothrappali");
    }};
}

public abstract static class MyMixIn {
    @JsonIgnore
    private Object objectField;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Object objectsList;
}

@Test
public void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
    // GIVEN
    // Right solution must work for any (MixIn(s) is out of questions) Jackson annotated class
    // without its modification.
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .addMixIn(Simpsons.class, MyMixIn.class)
            .addMixIn(BigBangTheory.class, MyMixIn.class);

    // WHEN
    String actual = mapper.writeValueAsString(new FavoriteShows());
    System.out.println(actual);

    // THEN
    // Expected: {"favorite":{"title":"The Simpsons"},"preferred":{"title":"The Big Bang Theory"}}
    assertThat(actual).isEqualTo("{\"favorite\":{\"title\":\"The Simpsons\"},\"preferred\":{\"title\":\"The Big Bang Theory\"}}");

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the way is to use custom `AnnotationIntrospector`.

```
class A {

    int three = 3;
    int four = 4;
    B b = new B();

    // setters + getters
}

class B {

    int one = 1;
    int two = 2;

    // setters + getters
}
```

To ignore all fields with type `B`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {
    @Override
    protected boolean _isIgnorable(Annotated a) {
        return super._isIgnorable(a)
                 // Ignore B.class
                 || a.getRawType() == B.class
                 // Ignore List<B>
                 || a.getType() == TypeFactory.defaultInstance()
                       .constructCollectionLikeType(List.class, B.class);
    }
});

String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new A());
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much!!!
I have added into your answer also how to check for `List<B>` - it is not so trivial, hope it helps others. Hope you do not mind.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using mixins you should be able to annotate with @JsonIgnoreType to have it ignore the class. [docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreType.html) For reference [Globally ignore class in Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697808/globally-ignore-class-in-jackson)

Comment: Hmmm, It does not work for, e.g.: `Objeck.class` - it filters out everything which I believe passes `instanceof Object`.
`addMixIn(Object.class, MixInWithJsonIgnoreType.class)`

Comment: Are you really using addMixIn(Object.class, MixInWithJsonIgnoreType.class) because of course that will cause everything to be excluded. You need to explicitly add the mixin to the correct implementation class.

Comment: Hmmm, I really need to exclude `Object.class` type properties ..... :(

Comment: I think you may be confusing yourself. Everything that isn't a primitive in Java is an Object. You would literally be excluding almost everything if you exclude Object. What is likely happening is the definition in the class of the property is Object but the class assigned is more specific, this is usually done when the type may be determined at runtime. You need to figure out what the actual class is at runtime you need to exclude it.  Otherwise you need to exclude the property instead of the type.

Comment: Generally, I do not want to filter out sub-types of whatever I want to ignore.

Comment: your solution is great in its simplicity for Jackson types. Thank you very much for your effort.