# How can I skip fields of certain types during serialization?

Tags: java, json, serialization, reflection, jackson

I have a Spring AOP service which intercepts a lot of different third-party controllers endpoints. My service runs an endpoint, gets the result DTO, serialize DTO to json with ObjectMapper, sends json to Kafka and return the DTO outside. The problem is: the service shouldn't serialise fields of particular types (e.g MultipartFile). I can't use @JsonIgnore annotation, because DTO should be returned outside without changes.
Can I make ObjectMapper skip fields of certain types? Or, maybe, copy the DTO and set this fields to null with reflection?

Comment: Where is your complete, minimal reproducer?

Comment: kriegaex, sorry, reproducer of what?

Comment: does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65568597/jackson-objectmapper-how-to-omit-ignore-fields-of-certain-type-from-serializa

Comment: @Eugene_Z, of your situation, of course. Nobody can debug and correct invisible code.Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: @kriegaex The question is how to configure Jackson. There's nothing to debug.

Comment: @kaqqao, the OP did not post any code, as is customary here. That code is helpful or even necessary to understand a question or its answer, is proven by your own example code. Basically, you were friendly enough to do the OP's job to provide sample code. Lucky for him, that you understood or at least were able to make an educated guess about what he was asking. Your guess is that the only problem is Jackson config, which might be right or wrong. BTW, the OP did not even mention Jackson in his question. It even was you who added the tag on his behalf.

Comment: @kaqqao, do you see now what I mean? Your educated guess was good, your effort laudable. But finally, your guess was not entirely correct, so the OP wrote and accepted his own answer. Suddenly, he came up with sample code and added more details about his situations. If he had let his code speak by providing a reproducer for his situation and current implementation, explaining what was wrong with it and how he expected it to function instead, you probably could have answered it in no time, reaping the fruits of your work by means of an accepted answer without much guessing or debate (with me).

Comment: Hence my meta comment about the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). An MCVE is the cornerstone of a good question and dramatically improves the probability of getting a spot-on answer quickly. My corresponding comments are meant to educate and guide users to ask better questions in the future for their own benefit and everyone else's.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have changeable list of prohibited classes in YAML properties file, so I can't use mixins. The task was solved in this way:

```
@Value("${classes-to-remove}")
private String classesToRemove;

public String getClearedJson(MyDTO myDTO) {
    List<String> fieldNamesToRemove = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Field field: myDTO.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (classesToRemove.contains(field.getType().getSimpleName())) {
            fieldNamesToRemove.add(field.getName());
            continue;
        }

        if (field.getGenericType() instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            ParameterizedType listType = (ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType();
            Class<?> listClass = (Class<?>) listType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            if (classesToRemove.contains(listClass.getSimpleName())) {
                fieldNamesToRemove.add(field.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myDTO);
    JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(json);
    ObjectNode object = (ObjectNode) jsonNode;
    fieldNamesToRemove.forEach(object::remove);
    String updatedJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    
    return updatedJson;
}
```

Comment: I showed you 2 very elegant ways to exclude dynamically configurable classes. Not sure why you'd prefer this downright hacky solution. E.g. you'll wrongly exclude classes in different packages if their simple name matches, you deal with only one level of generics and only with `ParameterizedType` etc. At the very least, don't `writeValueAsString` only to `readTree` - use `valueToTree` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Always remember that Jackson is literal magic and is endlessly customizable :)

There are many ways to achieve what you want.

Let's suppose you have the following DTO class and want to exclude `File`:

```java
public class SimpleDTO {

    private final File file;
    private final String name;

    @JsonCreator
    public SimpleDTO(@JsonProperty("file") File file, @JsonProperty("name") String name) {
        this.file = file;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

###### Mix-ins

You can create a mix-in such as:

```java
@JsonIgnoreType
public interface IgnoreTypeMixin {}
```

And then use it when serializing:

```java
//Pretend the File class was annotated by @JsonIgnoreType
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().addMixIn(File.class, IgnoreTypeMixin.class);

String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(new SimpleDTO(new File("/tmp/simple.txt"), "A kewl name"));
System.out.println(serialized); //Prints {"name":"A kewl name"}
```

Instead of `@JsonIgnoreType`, you could have also mixed-in `@JsonIgnore` to the `file` field in `SimpleDTO` or `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "file" })` or any other Jackson annotation. Here's an [overview of annotations used to ignore fields](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization).

Note: Do not create a new `ObjectMapper` each time. Configure one instance for serialization and share it forever.

###### Programmatic configuration

Mix-ins let you add annotations from the outside, but annotations are still static configuration. If you have to dynamically choose fields (not only by type) to ignore, annotations, mixed-in or not, won't suffice. Jackson, being magic and all, lets you achieve programmatically anything that can be done via annotations:

```java
public class FieldFilteringIntrospector extends NopAnnotationIntrospector {

    private final Set<Class<?>> ignoredTypes;

    public FieldFilteringIntrospector(Set<Class<?>> ignoredTypes) {
        this.ignoredTypes = Collections.unmodifiableSet(ignoredTypes);
    }

    public FieldFilteringIntrospector(Class<?>... ignoredTypes) {
        this.ignoredTypes = Arrays.stream(ignoredTypes).collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean isIgnorableType(AnnotatedClass ac) {
        return ignoredTypes.contains(ac.getRawType());
    }
}
```

And then use it when serializing:

```java
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("type-filter-module") {
    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
        super.setupModule(context);
        context.insertAnnotationIntrospector(new FieldFilteringIntrospector(File.class));
    }
};
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(module);

String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(new SimpleDTO(new File("/tmp/simple.txt"), "A kewl name"));
System.out.println(serialized); //Prints {"name":"A kewl name"}
```

By overriding other methods from `NopAnnotationIntrospector`, you can emulate other annotations, `@JsonIgnore` and others.

Note: Again, create an `ObjectMapper` only once.

Comment: Thanks! It Is really good way. Unfortunately, I have changeable list of prohibited classes in YAML properties file. So, I can't create list of mixins. I used another approach,  in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an object mapper to overcome this or can be used getDeclaredFields method to build a logic to remove unwanted attributes and return